# Using undefined attributes in html tags in ionic

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, html-lists

I want to use [grid-list](https://github.com/hootsuite/grid) for creating some nice tiles in my ionic application. I'm generating the elements of my grid like this:

```
<ion-content padding>

  <div class="grid-container" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <ul class="container" style="position:relative; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
      <li *ngFor="let item of items "
          class="grid-item"
          style="position:absolute"
          data-x="{{item.x}}"
          data-y="{{item.y}}"
          data-w="{{item.w}}"
          data-h="{{item.h}}">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

The `item` object in my componenet:

```
  items = [
    {w: 1, h: 1, x: 0, y: 0},
    {w: 1, h: 2, x: 0, y: 1},
    {w: 2, h: 2, x: 1, y: 0},
    {w: 1, h: 1, x: 1, y: 2},
    {w: 2, h: 1, x: 2, y: 2},
    {w: 1, h: 1, x: 3, y: 0},
    {w: 1, h: 1, x: 3, y: 1},
    {w: 1, h: 0, x: 4, y: 0}
  ];
```

However, this does not work because TypeScript is telling me that `data-w` etc. are not known properties of `<li>`, which I know. But shouldn't I be able to add them like this?

Also neither

```
  [data-x]="item.x"
  [data-y]="item.y"
  [data-w]="item.w"
  [data-h]="item.h"
```

nor

```
  [data-x]="{{item.x}}"
  [data-y]="{{item.y}}"
  [data-w]="{{item.w}}"
  [data-h]="{{item.h}}"
```

work and I don't know why. Same error.

```
Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'data-x' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to use `attr.`:

```
<li [attr.not-existing-property]="something"> </li>
```

if the property does not exist.